# Best Practice for Services with MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, design-patterns, asp.net-web-api

I am new to MVC and learned the concepts. But as a practical view, as a beginner,  little consfused.

MVC is a presentation pattern. But MVC also contains Controller and Model. These are the business and data logics. So how it migled in the presentation itself. Is my understanding right?

If i implement WCF Service  / Web Api how the approach will be? I read articles and forum's thread about this, but i didn't got it clearly.

Mostly said web api is the best combination and simply include in the controller. But then how the layer is seperated as presentation and service layer? Here the service layer (Web api ) is specifically for the MVC application / web UI only. Not getting generally.

I used WCF like Service Layer as one application and Business Layer and Data Layer as class libariries. Here i can host the service in iis and access from anywherer. How this service is used in the MVC application? Simply avoid implementing controller and model and simple use view with jquery?

Please give the correct apporach with WCF and Web API..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got several questions, so I'll try to answer all of them.

> MVC is a presentation pattern. But MVC also contains Controller and
>   Model. These are the business and data logics. So how it migled in the
>   presentation itself. Is my understanding right?

The `controller` is presentation-layer.  It really should act like a *coordinator* and not contain any business or persistence logic.  The `model` certainly can have business logic, but not any persistence logic.  Persistence is related to infrastructure and doesn't belong in your model or controller.

> If i implement WCF Service / Web Api how the approach will be? I read
>   articles and forum's thread about this, but i didn't got it clearly

Your service can be separate from the MVC project, although it's acceptable to include your Web API in your MVC project.  Personally, I think it should be separate.  Keep in mind that what you've read about services in an MVC project may be referring to a local service or repository in a DDD (domain driven design) sense.  It's way different.

> Mostly said web api is the best combination and simply include in the
>   controller. But then how the layer is seperated as presentation and
>   service layer? Here the service layer (Web api ) is specifically for
>   the MVC application / web UI only. Not getting generally

WCF or Web API?  Choose the best one for your needs and skills.  Either way, I think it's best to keep the service separate.  Again, don't confuse a DDD service with an autonomous service-layer.

> I used WCF like Service Layer as one application and Business Layer
>   and Data Layer as class libariries. Here i can host the service in iis
>   and access from anywherer. How this service is used in the MVC
>   application? Simply avoid implementing controller and model and simple
>   use view with jquery?

Yes, you can call the service from your view's JQuery code or from your controller, it depends on your needs.  It's probably better to create a local service in your MVC project that will contact your services and data-stores.  Then, have your controller use this local service for its data needs.

Comment: Thanks friend. Like you told i also read that View is User Interface , Controller is UI Process so both are presentation. Model is business entities. Is my understanding right? I got the answers but little confused in the last answer. You already told that seperate project is good for service so that service can be accessed in the controller. But in that last answer you again specified that better create web api in the mvc itself. Please explain this. Also if i access from view using jquery no need to add web reference but in controller i need to add reference.

Comment: You are right, the controller and view are presentation layer.  The "service" I am referring to in the MVC project is not a WCF or Web API service.   It's really another layer of abstraction (a class) that serves as the data gateway for your controller. It will make calls to external datasources and return them to your controller. It's a DDD concept. You can use JQuery to make calls to your controllers or make calls directly to your Web API or WCF service.

Answer (score 1):

In a simple application, I often see two projects in a solution, An MVC project for the web front-end and a class library for data access, lets call that "core". The core project contains all of the ORM related classes and a service class implementing an interface, lets call it IService which handles business logic.

When a request comes in to the MVC controller, the controller will call IService to pull back the data it needs and pass that information onto the view. In this approach there aren't any "Models" in your MVC folder, but the ORM Model is being used. For more complex pages, you would create an MVC Model, to combine several pieces of data returned from ISservice and present them in a way that makes sense to the user.

In a larger project, the core project which contains IService may be 1-many WCF or Web API services. This gives you more flexibility for scaling the application and allows your web pages to make ajax calls directly to the data layer.

In this scenario, when a request comes into the controller, it would still call IService, but this service is actually a WCF or Web API service.